# Why does my loop work correctly on the first iteration but not on the full set I'm looping through?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, glob, shutil

I am trying to rename folders in bulk based on the folders/files contained within them (then moving the image files at the end of each path into they're respective model/color folder directories).
Each folder/file has a similar naming convention of MODEL_COLOR.

The code below works, though seems to only be working correctly on the first folder, in other words, the folders are being renamed correctly but the last leg of code seems to be taking the folder which contains the images and moves it to the corresponding path, instead of specifically moving the images to the corresponding path and dropping the folder they're originally in.

On the first folder the loop iterates, it actually moves the images to the correct Model > Color directory, though on all folders after that it seems to be moving the **folder** containing the images into the correct Model > Color directory, **instead of just moving the images alone into the corresponding directory**.

After looking at the forums I've seen similar issues where when changing the directory or deleting certain instances, the loop can't iterate correctly due to the initial set changing during the looping process (i.e. deleting or renaming part of the path while iterating). I'm pretty sure it's a simple fix but I can't seem to find the solution that'll work best.

Standard FolderNames:

- CL4003IN_45F
- CL4003IN_56F
- CL40157U_01D
- CL40157U_52H

```
import glob, os, shutil

folder = 'C:\\testing'
# create new folder directory based on Model/Color [is working, but moves file_path into base directory]

# arr = []    
for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*_*')):
    new_dir = file_path.rpartition('_')[0]
    new_subdir = file_path.rpartition('_')[2]
    try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(new_dir, new_subdir))
    except WindowsError:
        # Handle the case where the target dir already exist.
        pass
    shutil.move(file_path, os.path.join(new_dir, new_subdir))
    # arr.append(file_path)
```

Comment: Why does every line add an extra layer of indentation?

Comment: That was a copy/paste mistake, just fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you don't see the actual error is that you catch too many errors in your `except:` statement.

You intend to catch `FileExistsError`, so you should also just look for this one. Otherwise you would have noticed that the code in fact throws a `FileNotFoundError`.

The reason for that is that `os.mkdir` does **not** automatically create parent directories. It only creates directories one layer deep, but your code requires two layers of new directories.

For that, you would have to use `os.makedirs(...)` instead. Conveniently, `os.makedirs` also accepts an `exist_ok` flag, which gets rid of your entire `try:`-`except:` construct.

A further annotation is that you have a lot of duplicate calculations in your code:

- `file_path.rpartition('_')` gets calculated twice
- `os.path.join(new_dir, new_subdir)` gets calculated twice

I'd suggest storing those in meaningful variables. This speeds up your code, makes it more readable and more maintainable.

Here's a reworked version of your code:

```
import glob
import os
import shutil

folder = 'C:\\testing'

for file_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*_*')):
    (new_dir, _, new_subdir) = file_path.rpartition('_')
    target_path = os.path.join(new_dir, new_subdir)

    os.makedirs(target_path, exist_ok=True)

    shutil.move(file_path, target_path)
```

---

### Further improvements/fixes

There's still a bunch wrong in your code:

- You don't check if the thing found by `glob` is a file
- Splitting by `_` does not stop at the directory divider. This means that something like `C:\\my_files\\bla` will get split into `C:\\my` and `files\\bla`.

I think you didn't care about either of those, because you thought 'the user would not use the script like this'. But this is actually a case that **will** happen:

- You have a file `C:\\my_files\\CL4003IN_45F`, which will get moved to `C:\\my_files\\CL4003IN\\45F\\CL4003IN_45F`, as expected.
- You run the script again. The script will find `C:\\my_files\\CL4003IN`. It doesn't check if it's a folder, so it will process it anyway. It will then split it into `C:\\my` and `files\\CL4003IN`.
- The entire folder `C:\\my_files\\CL4003IN` will get moved to `C:\\my\\files\\CL4003IN`. Therefore the original file `CL4003IN_45F` ends up in `C:\\my\\files\\CL4003IN\\CL4003IN\\45F\\CL4003IN_45F`

The solution is:

- only use `rpartition` on the *filename*, not the entire path
- check if it actually is a file, or a directory

Most of these tasks get solved easier with `pathlib`. I took the liberty of rewriting your code and fixing those issues:

```
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path('C:\\testing')

for file_path in folder.iterdir():
    file_name = file_path.name

    # Ignore directories
    if not file_path.is_file():
        continue

    # Split the filename by '_'
    (target_dir, _, target_subdir) = file_name.rpartition('_')

    # If no '_' found, ignore
    if not target_dir:
        continue

    # Compute the target path and create it if necessary
    target_path = folder / target_dir / target_subdir
    target_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    # Move the file to its new position
    target_file_path = target_path / file_name
    file_path.rename(target_file_path)
```

One last remark: `folder.iterdir()` actually **does** return an iterator. But that shouldn't be a problem in this case, as we explicitely check if the path is an existing file and not a directory or something that already got deleted. But if you want to be 100% safe write `list(folder.iterdir())`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tried this but still didn't solve the issue. I also tried defining glob in it's own variable before the loop, but still to no avail. Result remains the same where first iteration processes correctly, but all following iterations miss a step.. any additional suggestions would be most appreciated!

Comment: Now that I understood your problem, I wonder why it processed the first iteration sucessfully ...

Comment: Thank you for this! This is great stuff, will definitely take me further in my python journey. The fix that i applied worked for what I was trying to do, but your approach covers a whole lot more that will definitely come in handy in this project. Again, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Completing the iteration of `glob` before the loop by storing it in a `list` helped avoid some unwanted errors.

```
#...
for file_path in list(glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*_*')
...#
```

But by modifying my code and removing the following from the loop:

```
try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(new_dir, new_subdir))
except WindowsError:
    pass
```

Allowed the code to iterate through all the folders in the directory without transferring the folder before the file into the `new_dir > new_subdir` directory.

The new code that works across a multitude of folders within a directory is:

```
import glob, os, shutil

folder = 'C:\\testing'

# create new folder directory based on Model > Color

for file_path in list(glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*_*'), recursive=True)):
    new_dir = file_path.rpartition('_')[0]
    new_subdir = file_path.rpartition('_')[2]
    shutil.move(file_path, os.path.join(new_dir, new_subdir))
```

This may not be the most efficient code (and may not work across all instances, that remains to be determined!), though definitely works as intended for now.

Special thanks to those that helped with their suggestions.

Comment: I think your answer doesn't actually solve the initial problem. I've found it, give me a minute to update my answer

Comment: Also, after further research, `glob.glob` already returns a list and not an interator, therefore it *is* already finished before the loop gets entered. Therefore changing the filesystem while iterating is not an issue.

Comment: If you want to mark an answer as a solution to your problem, the site has a feature for that. Click the checkmark on the left of  the answer.